# Visual Studio 2012 express for Web doesn't run unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a c# project created in VS2010 and then imported into 2012 express (web). When I build it, however, the unit tests don't run. Going into the test explorer gives me the option to hit "run all", which simply causes the build to run again without the tests.

thinking it may be caused by the import I created, in 2012, a new project in the solution as a unit test project, with a simple test (asserting true==false). This shows up in the solution explorer with the correct icon. however, no amount of building/rebuilding/cleaning has yet caused this test to run either.

I have update 3 installed, and have changed nothing to my knowledge that would affect the tests. Anyone know what's wrong?

EDIT: I created a new solution containing nothing but a single unit test (for `true==false`) this runs as expected, so it is not the vesion of VS that is the problem, I just don't know what other configuration options could cause this to fail in this way.

Comment: I guess unit testing is not supported in 'express for web'

Comment: Verify in the `Configuration manager` if the test project is checked for your current configuration.

Comment: All pojects in the Configuration manager are checked to be built

Answer (score 0):

Found that there were some configuration files in the solution directory that were causing problems. deleting them fixed the issue.

Comment: Which configuration files? Can you paste here the list? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got into same issue when upgrading solution from VS 2010 to 2012. All tests disapeared. I got over this by deleting the old (VS2010) solution file. Then, I created new one using VS2012 and added all the projects to the new solution. After Rebuild all tests appeared in tests explorer.